# Not catching multiple exceptions

Tags: java, exception

If the input is between 1-26, return the value. When I input a number over 27 or a letter, it doesn't catch and handle the exception only skips the line to continue looping.

Why does it do this, and how can I fix this?

```
 public int checkInput(int userInput) {

    boolean valid = false;

    do {
        try {
            if (userInput <= 26 || userInput > 0) {
                break;
            }
            valid = true;

        } catch (NumberFormatException | InputMismatchException |
                 ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            valid = false;
            System.out.println("The input is invalid, please enter the answer again.");
            userInput = sc.nextInt();
        }
    } while (!valid);

    return userInput;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code doesn't throw any exceptions. Therefore the catch block will never be reached

Comment: This code won't even compile.

Comment: Instead of break, you should throw a user defined exception

Comment: If your intention is to keep prompting till a valid value is entered, there is no need to throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas Kläger wrote, the `catch` clause is never reached.
Nothing inside the `try` clause casts exceptions:

```
if (userInput <= 26 || userInput > 0) {
    break;
}
valid = true;
```

You haven't provided all the code since we can't see how `checkInput(int)` is called.
But I assume that you call it like this:

```
public void takeInput() {
    int input = sc.nextInt();
    checkInput(input);
}
```

The exception happens at the line `int input = sc.nextInt()` but this is not covered by a `try` clause.

---

You are using exceptions as a part of your control flow.
That is considered bad practice, see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why.

The following works as intended.

```
package main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExceptionHandling {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ExceptionHandling exceptionHandling = new ExceptionHandling();
        exceptionHandling.getInputUntilValid();
    }

    private final Scanner scanner;

    public ExceptionHandling() {
        this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void getInputUntilValid() {
        boolean isValidInput = false;
        while (!isValidInput) {
            if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                Optional<Integer> integerInput = getInt();
                isValidInput = checkInput(integerInput);
                if (!isValidInput) {
                    System.out.println("The input is invalid, please enter the answer again.");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Valid.");
    }

    private Optional<Integer> getInt() {
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            int input = scanner.nextInt();
            return Optional.of(input);
        }
        else {
            scanner.next();
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkInput(Optional<Integer> input) {
        return input.map(value -> checkBounds(value)).orElse(false);
    }

    private boolean checkBounds(int userInput) {
        return 0 < userInput && userInput <= 26;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. i just try to use Recursion concept.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestRun {

    static int first_value = 27;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int value = checkInput2(first_value);

        System.out.println(value);

    }

    public static int checkInput2(int userInput) {

        if (!checkvalue(userInput)) {

            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("The input is invalid, please enter the answer again.");
                userInput = sc.nextInt();
                checkInput2(userInput);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                checkInput2(first_value);
            }
        }
        return userInput;
    }

    public static boolean checkvalue(int userInput) {

        if (userInput <= 26 && userInput > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```